# Mongoose: return a custom object as response to a POST request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

*Sorry if the title isn't very clear, I didn't know how to phrase the problem I'm facing, in the title.*

I have a signup form. The user submits the form and server checks in mongoose if the email already exists in the database. If it doesn't, it lets you continue with signup. I created some additional objects within the model.find function that I want to send as a response to the post request. How can I do that? Please take a look at the code for better understanding.

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

    User.find({email: req.body.email})
        .then(res => {
            if (res.length === 0) {
                console.log('didnt find the email')

                const id = uuidv4()
                const code = '1234'

                //I want to send this object as a response to the post request
                const obj = {id, code}


                Model.create(obj)

                return obj

                //I tried sending the response from here but that doesn't work either.
                //return res.json(obj)

            } else {
                console.log('Error')
            }
        })
    //This return statement doesn't return the obj I want to send because it's not accessible by it.
    return res.json(obj)
}
```

Comment: What do you want to be responded, the user object along with `{ id, code }` ? can you put an example?

Comment: I just want to return any object or variable from within the promise as a response to the post request.

Comment: You are overriding the `res` variable from http *response* with the mongoose query *result*, just change `.then(res =>` to `.then(users =>`, then you can do `res.send(users)`. If you only want one user you can do `User.findOne`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use **async** function and then store the data of the User.find function in a variable. Then the variable can be used as a response to the post request.

```
app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {

const var1 = await User.find({email: req.body.email})
    .then(res => {
        if (res.length === 0) {
            console.log('didnt find the email')

            const id = uuidv4()
            const code = '1234'

            //I want to send this object as a response to the post request
            const obj = {id, code}


            Model.create(obj)

            return obj

        } else {
            console.log('Error')
        }
    })
return res.json(var1)
}
```